# Mediawiki bot to find out the changes of the last hours

Tags: mediawiki

**Asking for:**

I want to use a bot (mediawiki api or direct database access), that find out the changes of all pages of the last hours. I need a diff and want to process the text afterwards. A guess into the right direction (diff of last edits) is enough. I know how to iterate pages.

**Background:**

I want to process the diff to find out new download links as part of template call. For this step I don't need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pywikibot](https://github.com/wikimedia/pywikibot), This should be a (maybe) good start:

```
from pywikibot import Site
from datetime import timedelta

my_site = Site(language, family) # Or set default site with pywikibot config file

# From this object you may get the changes by timestamp, pywikibot.Timestamp are datetime objects as well.
current_time = my_site.getcurrenttime()
my_site.recentchanges(start = current_time, end=current_time - timedelta(hours=6))
```

You can iterate the pages which changed in the last X (6) hours and for each one:

```
from pywikibot import Page

current_page = Page(my_site, page_title)  # Page title written in the recentchanges 
return object
revisions = current_page.revisions(total=some_number, content=True)
```

After that you can use some internals api to get the diff between two revisions:

```
from pywikibot.diff import PatchManager

PatchManager(first_rev_text, second_rev_text).print_hunks()  # print_hunks is for interactive changes, but you can work with any internals api here (that might not be simple).
```

That not fully code as you need but you can work from here and add some more logic to solve your case,
Good luck:)